# How to collect goods from a French shop, package and deliver them abroad?

Tags: france

I need to:

1. Collect physical goods from a certain French shop (they don't do delivery).
2. Package them properly with bubble wrap because they're fragile (the shop won't package it that way).
3. Send them abroad.

Also, I don't speak French and I cannot do those three steps myself.

What service should I use?